# Rails MongoDb Project on Heroku wont Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

Hi Guys I recently downloaded an open source code "ribbot" from git hub git://github.com/barmstrong/ribbot.git after setting up my local environment I was able to get the code running on my local machine. I decided to use heroku for for my web base solution and have installed herokulabs. When running the site I get the following heroku logs error:

```
    2012-04-17T16:51:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2012-04-17T16:51:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
    2012-04-17T16:51:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
    2012-04-17T16:51:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec 2012-04-17T16:51:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-17 16:51:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=5078
2012-04-17T16:51:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-17 16:51:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-04-17T16:51:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-17 16:51:58] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-04-17T16:51:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:5078
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: localhost:11211 failed (count: 0)
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 208.124.140.154 at 2012-04-17 16:52:01 +0000
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://herokuapp.com/forums
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 9ms
2012-04-17T16:52:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET quiet-stream-2681.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=703ms status=302 bytes=93
```

my mongoid.yml looks like this:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: ribbot_development

test:
  host: localhost
  database: ribbot_test

production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 11211 is memcached (likely)... so maybe you are using memcached locally and need to add the heroku add-on for memcached.

Comment: I will try that now. Thank you so much this is an update to this problem that ive been having for a while. Its good to knwo its not a dead end

Comment: It seems to still be throwing an error however it does say Dalli/SASL Authenticated